# How to increase the number of lines in Code::Blocks xterm console output?

Tags: console, xterm

I want to increase the number of lines in Code::Blocks xterm console output to 1000 lines.  I tried setting "Terminal to launch console programs" under "Environment Settings" > "General Settings" to:

```
xterm -sl 1000 -T $TITLE -e
```

But there were only 747 lines outputted.

Answer (score 1):

The [manual page](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html) gives a clue:

> **[`-sl`](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#OPTIONS:-sl)** *number*
>   This option specifies the number of lines to save that have
>   been scrolled off the top of the screen.  This corresponds to
>   the **[`saveLines`](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html)** resource.  The default is "64".

Setting the resource value would bypass whatever problems you might have with Code::Blocks configuration.

Comment: Well "-sl number" is what I'm using.  So why isn't it working?

Comment: Code::Blocks may be overriding the option in its launcher.  I'd suggest tracing the program to prove that...